# material angular: sidenav component, md-sidenave

Tags: angular, angular-material

Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
`md-sidenav` is not a known element:
1. If `md-sidenav` is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If `md-sidenav` is a Web Component then add `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` to the `@NgModule.schemas` of this component to suppress this message.

```
("<md-sidenav-container class="example-container">
  [ERROR ->]<md-sidenav #sidenav class="example-sidenav">
    Jolly good!
  </md-sidenav>
"): ng:///SharedModule/SidenavComponent.html@1:2
'md-sidenav-container' is not a known element:
1. If 'md-sidenav-container' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'md-sidenav-container' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("[ERROR ->]<md-sidenav-container class="example-container">
  <md-sidenav #sidenav class="example-sidenav">
    "): ng:///SharedModule/SidenavComponent.html@0:0
```

Comment: which version of material are you using ?

Comment: "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.10",

Comment: Refer this link https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: @Vignesh: I'm adding thes module into app.module.ts

Comment: import { MaterialModule, MdSidenavModule } from '@angular/material';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

Comment: Then add this in html file: ``<md-sidenav-container class="example-container">
  <md-sidenav #sidenav class="example-sidenav">
    Jolly good!
  </md-sidenav>

  <div class="example-sidenav-content">
    <button type="button" md-button (click)="sidenav.open()">
      Open sidenav
    </button>
  </div>

</md-sidenav-container>

Comment: Have you imported MaterialModule under in AppModule

Comment: Yes `code` imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule,
    MdSidenavModule
  ],

Comment: @SalimIbrogimov are you using webpack (or) system.js. And post your package.json code

Comment: @Vignesh: I'm using webpack, and I already fixed that issue

Comment: @Vignesh: I've got app.module.ts & shared.module.ts; I imported material into app.module instead shared.module; now I change it; and it's work fine!

Comment: Already i asked have you imported MaterialModule in AppModule. You said Yes

Comment: @Vignesh: Thats true, problem is this? that I need to import MaterialModul undel SharedModule